# Can I play gaming in this (my) laptop or just in a desktop computer?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, graphics-card, cpu

I currently have an HP Laptop G62 with AMD Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series that has a ~2.4GHz CPUs (2 CPUs) and a 3GB RAM.

I am playing Crossfire 2.0 at this laptop for 2 years, along with other major games such as CounterStrike and L4D2.

According to my mom and the "technician" that fixed my graphics card last couple of days ago that I can't play those games in this laptop because it doesn't meet the requirements of my laptop. So I checked CrossFire's, Minecraft's and CounterStrike's requirements. I passed all the specs/requirements needed for those 3 games. I ignored it because: Why I can't? I passed the requirements!

After 1 and a half months, my graphics card broke again.

It was replaced for $30.

Now I am confused: Can I really play games at this laptop?

Please help.

Comment: You have the laptop and the games so try playing them. If you're satisfied enough with the performance and user experience you get that you don't want to get into gaming any deeper, then you're OK. As a side note your strategy of buying dirt cheap graphics cards and replacing them when they wear out would make more sense if you didn't waste your money on technicians for fixing such a common occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern games (or rather modern computers running software) usually don't damage your hardware the way you describe it even if you don't meet the minimum requirements: if your computer is powerful enough it will run the way you expect it to - if it doesn't meet it it won't start the game or you will experience drops in frame rate etc. If a game/software really is too demanding to your hardware, temperatures in the computer might rise to unhealthy ranges at which point the computer should turn off on its own.
As this is a laptop you might want to check, if the fans are running or if they collected too much dust as this might lead to described temperature problems.
Btw: a notebook graphics card with a certain GPU is **not** the same as the corresponding desktop graphics card so just finding the number as "supported" doesn't mean that the mobile version of the GPU is officially supported (although usually nowadays the game runs anyway).